# Unable to catch SIGHUP signal

Tags: c++, linux

I am facing a strange problem while handling the **SIGHUP** signal.

I need to execute some commands in interactive mode.
So I wrote some code using the pseudo terminal concept. Below is the link I referred to this [article](http://www.rkoucha.fr/tech_corner/pty_pdip.html).

In the link, they use the fork concept to start the master and slave terminals.
Once the task is completed, both master and file descriptors are closed using *close(fd)* command.

However, since fork will display the duplicate process and this is not allowed in our project, I have used thread instead of fork.
I am able to close the slave file descriptor properly without any problem.
But I am not able to close the master *fd*.

After some analysis, I observe that while trying to close the master *fd*, it sends **SIGHUP** signal. This is ok if I use *fork()* concept, but unfortunately I have used thread and so my process is getting terminated.

If I don't close it there is a *fd* leakage.
So I want to ignore the **SIGHUP** signal. But when I wrote the program to catch the signal, I was able to catch all signals except this one.
Could anyone please help me on this part?

Is the way to catch **SIGHUP** different from other signals?

Note: We are using amf framework to keep our service available. When I keep service independent, I am able to catch the signal and when it is in amf, I am not able to catch the signal.
Any quick help is appreciated. Now I don't have time to do any design changes. I simply want to avoid the memory leakage.

Comment: Signals with multi-threading is different from single-threaded processes. If you have multiple threads, some signals could be sent to certain threads, or maybe even to a *random* thread. There are ways to block signals in specific threads, so they will not receive signals. I suggest you start reading [the `signal(7)` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and go from there to learn more.

Comment: [AMF](https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/AMF) = Advanced Media Framework?

Comment: Availability Management Framework